# OS X won't move files to Trash

Tags: macos, trash

I am trying to delete some things and put them in my trash. It says "Moving items to trash", but the dialog is now open since 24 hours.

When I try to empty my trash it won't let me due to the fact my "files are still moving". How do I delete the files and empty my trash bin?

Comment: I hate to ask, but have you tried turning it off and on again?

Answer (score 2):

Relaunch your Finder and try again.

Run `killall Finder` in Terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Close the moving items to trash then open terminal and enter the below command:

> sudo rm -rf ~/.Trash/*

Note: this will ask for your password as it requires elevated privileges

This will force delete your trash items then try deleting the files again. please get back to me if the files still won't move to trash after this

Comment: I'd probably suggest double and triple checking the path. You don't want to be `rm -rf /`.

Comment: I would hope that it would be a copy paste job not a look type; look type that Ruby is doing as `rm -rf /` would ruin there day

Comment: This will not work since there's no `~/.trash` in OS X. You probably mean `~/.Trash` – however the OP's problem is that the files aren't even moving there in the first place, so I would suggest logging out and back in or looking at whether there are some locked files first.

Comment: The recommendation to clear trash first comes from previous troubleshooting exp with OS X and trash issues also there are 2 questions "How do I delete the files and empty my trash bin?"

Answer (score -1):

My SOLUTION: Use a *different* microSD-to-USB adapter. Really.

"Bad one": LG MicroSD Adapter, the size of a regular SD card.
           With this adapter, all files are read only.

Good one: Photo Capture the spot. It is a bulky adapter for micro SD/TF cards.
          With this adapter, all files are read/write.

I switch the card from one adapter to the other without any change and files are read only or read/write.

Comment: This appears to be an answer to a different question. There is no mention of MicroSD cards in the question.